# How can I get the value of two inputs, calculate them and put the result in another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to refactor this code to improve performance. I take the value of two inputs, and I need to calculate them and display the result in another:

```
var price;
var percentage;
var value;

function total() {
    value = ((price* (percentage/ 100)) + parseFloat(price));

    $("#Total").val(value.toFixed(2));
}

$("#price").keyup(function () {
    price = $(this).val();
    total()
});

$("#percentage").keyup(function () {
    percentage = $(this).val();
    total()
});
```

Comment: Get the values of the inputs in the `total()` function, rather than updating global variables after each keyup.

Comment: Also, note that `PorcentajeMargenGanancia` != `percentage`

Comment: but I need it to be with the keyup event

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, I corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use global variables like this. They could cause [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

```js
// this self executing function will prevent the *Field variables to be bound to your browsers' window variable.
(function() {

  let priceField = $("#price");
  let percentageField = $("#percentage");
  let totalField = $("#Total");

  function total() {
    let price = priceField.val();
    let percentage = percentageField.val();

    let value = (price * (percentage/ 100)) + parseFloat(price);

    totalField.val(value.toFixed(2));
  }

  priceField.keyup(function () {
    total()
  });
  percentageField.keyup(function () {
    total()
  });

})()
```

I have to say this is a solution for your question, but it's not the nicest one out there. But based on my guess, this solution needs to be simple.

A few extra tips would be to selectively search for input fields like `$("input#price")` to prevent any other potential collisions, although an id should be unique.

I also would suggest to add some protection in the code. If anybody entered some nonnumeric values, what should happen? Should they be stripped from the input before the calculations are made, or should they trigger an error to the user stating that the user's input is not valid?